# Can I convert a non-xib app to use xibs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xib

I have a working app with a navigation controller, two view controllers, two views, a model object, and no xib file. The views are created programatically.  Now I'd like to build the same app using IB and xib files. Does anyone know of a writeup that explains how to add xib files and delete the program statements they replace? If not, then something that discusses the equivalences between xib library elements and program statements?

Why do I want to do this? Because I'm trying to understand what xib files do and how they interact with program statements and I thought this would be a good learning exercise. I made one try at it but couldn't get it to compile. In fact, every time I use xib files, except following textbook examples, I get hopelessly tangled up in code that won't compile or doesn't work if it does compile. So I must have some basic misconception. I need to figure out what xib files are doing behind the scenes. They seem potentially very powerful but I won't use them if I don't understand what they're doing.

I read elsewhere in stack overflow that they are a serialized version of a compiled view (or something like that). I understand that conceptually. I'm thoroughly familiar with Python's pickle files. But that doesn't explain much in practice.

Answer (score 1):

A nib/xib contains the information needed to create and connect objects together. Basically, it contains instance variable and class information for the objects it contains. To load one, you use the UINib class (NSNib in Mac OS X), or the NSBundle loadNib… methods. NSBundle's methods are easier to use, and I would suggest using them unless you will load a nib several times. For iOS, you would typically use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibNameWithoutExtension" owner:self options:nil];`. The owner does not have to be `self`. It is the object represented by the "File's Owner" object in IB and will receive any connections made to that object. The options parameter can be used to get the top level objects in the nib, but you usually use outlets instead. When a nib is loaded, the objects inside it are allocated and instantiated (using initWithCoder:), and connections are created using setter methods, or by setting the instance variables directly.